# In Firefox, how to make middle click be exactly identical to Ctrl+Click?

Tags: firefox

On a default Firefox profile, Middle Click does the same thing as Ctrl+Click - for most of the sites, anyway. There are some sites where this doesn't work; either a new tab is not created at all (instead the click occurs in the current tab), or a tab is created but a click *also* occurs in the current tab.

Is it possible to configure Middle Click to be absolutely identical to Ctrl+Click, so that they never do different things?

Comment: More than the solution to the problem, would someone have an actual explanation ? I'm curious why even such thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Phoshi's answer using an AutoHotkey script](https://superuser.com/questions/30243/in-firefox-how-to-make-middle-click-be-exactly-identical-to-ctrlclick/30244#30244) is a nice workaround. I recommend replacing his AutoHotkey script with this modification:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive Mozilla Firefox
MButton::
Send ^{LButton}
#IfWinActive
```

What improvement does this make? Phoshi's script (i.e., using `MButton::IfWinActive, Mozilla Firefox` and so forth) will make it so the middle mouse button (outside of Firefox and other windows with "Mozilla Firefox" in the title) can only send a middle mouse *click*—middle-drag or middle-button-hold gestures will be impossible while the script is active. (Also, *all* middle-mouse-button gestures are disabled in "Mozilla Firefox"-titled windows.)

Also, `SetTitleMatchMode, 2` allows the script to match Firefox even if "Mozilla Firefox" is later in the window title (otherwise it will only match if "Mozilla Firefox" is at the beginning of the window title).

Comment: The `#IfWinActive` directive "switches off" the hotkeys and hotstrings listed after it unless the described window is active. Using `#IfWinActive` without any parameters on the rest of the line returns behavior to normal for the hotkeys and hotstrings listed afterward.

Answer (score 4):

```
MButton::
IfWinActive, Mozilla Firefox
send ^{LButton}
else
send {MButton}
return
```

in autohotkey would do it. Note that this turns middle click into control and left -everywhere- in firefox, not just for links.

edit: take out the additional linebreaks, I can't get them one line apart for some reason :\

Comment: @Phoshi - use the "Code Sample" option (the 1's & 0's icon) to display as code. I don't have enough rep here to do it for you so you can see.

Comment: Hmm good idea, somehow I never considered a solution outside of Firefox. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Aaaah, thanks Chris :)
Good luck, rom :) (Authotkey is a great tool, it can do just about anything <3)

Comment: What can't Autohotkey fix?

Comment: Obviously nothing on SuperUser, I start believing.

Comment: I don't know. I've used it in everything from web development, to copypaste code (you mean I can copy the end of the line too, and have the cursor put the contents of the clipboard where the only bit that changes goes? InCREDIBLE), to general everyday use, to window management, to gaming, to work processing, to taking screenshots (autoupload to remote server, you say?), to forum BBCode, to more! :D

Answer (score 3):

If you use TabMixPlus, you can configure all mouse actions, including middle click. This works on every platform.