# In Chrome, how to make middle click be exactly identical to Ctrl+Click?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

Sometimes crummy websites intercept middle clicks and prevent them opening links in a new tab. `Ctrl-left click` and `Right click->Open in new tab` behave correctly. Even [the BBC screws this up](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-38312935) (middle click any link).

Similarly to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/30243/in-firefox-how-to-make-middle-click-be-exactly-identical-to-ctrlclick), is there a way to make a middle click act as if you ctrl-left clicked in Chrome? I don't want to disable javascript and I don't want middle-click behaviour changed system-wide.